# "they do not incur guilt and die"

Tags: exodus

In Exodus 28:42-43 (NASB)

> 42 You shall make for them linen undergarments to cover their bare flesh; they shall reach from the waist even to the thighs. 43 And they shall be on Aaron and on his sons when they enter the tent of meeting, or when they approach the altar to minister in the Holy Place, so that **they do not incur guilt and die**. It shall be a statute forever to him and to his descendants after him.

Is this expression an hyperbole?

Comment: Do you not know the story of Nadab and Abihu? God didn't exagerate when talking about his tabernacle.

Comment: _Hyperbole (Rhetoric). A figure of speech consisting in exaggerated or extravagant statement_. [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90286?rskey=ceVQUD&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid). Does God _**ever**_ express himself in an 'exaggerated' or 'extravagant' manner ? Does he not convey truth faithfully, at all times ?

Comment: @NigelJ HM... would [this be an exception to what you say](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/54856/27054)?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 The multi-upvoted and accepted answer, to the question to which you link, proves that Tyre _was never re-built_. The specific _answer_ to which you draw attention is factually incorrect. And I have now down-voted it.

Comment: @NigelJ his interpretation is still valid making the statement an hyperbole

Comment: @NigelJ I'm not stating that I agree with him when he says it was "falsifiable" (that I disagree), just that the hyperbole reason I find yo address that concern he brings and he can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not hyperbole. Showing your nakedness (e.g. not having the right garment) is equivalent to being in a state of spiritual sin before God, and results in death.

This refers to some long running idioms in the Old Testament that are very useful to know for proper exegesis.

### The spiritual holographic principle

To understand this idea, note that "Presence" of God, is literally "face" of God (Hebrew "paneh") and occurs over 2,000 times in the Old Testament. It is one of the most important word pictures in the Old Testament.  There are common idioms about the importance of seeking God's face (1 Chron 16.11), God hiding his face (Eze. 39.24, Exodus 33.23), Adam hiding from God's face (Gen 3.8), the wicked believing God's face is turned elsewhere (Psalm 10.11), etc.

It is not just God's presence, it's a general idiom (e.g. Ex 10.28) but something special happens when God's face is involved, as God sees everything, so something hidden from God's face no longer exists. This creates all sorts of opportunities.

For example the Hebrew word for "forgive" is the same word as "cover". Now the correct interpretation of this is *not* to say that the sin is only "covered up" and not really forgiven - as that would be superimposing an English idiom onto the Hebrew, and we are trying to understand the Hebrew, so we take it at face value (pun intended) and accept the two-dimensionality.

Thus the idea is that something interferes with the line of sight from God's face to the sin. This intervening thing is often the "garment", but not always -- for example in the Temple it was a veil or curtain (Lev 4.6), and in other situations, it was a cloud that obstructed the line of sight. To be in a state of righteousness -- or forgiveness -- is to have a clean garment, because God sees the garment and **thus the covering is your spiritual condition**.

You want to avoid a situation in which God sees your nakedness (your sin). If God does not "see" the sin, the sin does not exist. What God sees is the garment, therefore

- the garment must fully cover the flesh (the flesh is sinful)
- the garment must itself be clean (or white)

### Applications

Having an understanding of these word pictures, many passages in the Bible become easier to understand and provide a richer exegesis:

- Adam and Eve, after sinning, suddenly realized they were naked (they didn't know before??), hid from God's face and quickly made garments for themselves out of leaves. God then made a proper garment for them out of the skin of an animal (a lamb or goat), which pre-figures the sacrificial offerings. (Gen 3.21) In a culture which did not have this holographic notion, there would not be so much emphasis on Adam and Eve's clothing.
- The enormous attention to detail in describing the priestly garment, two entire chapters just in the the book of Exodus (Ex 28, 39), including the number of layers, type of yarn, color of yarn, types of stones to decorate it with, how they should be attached, etc. As much attention is paid in the Law describing what priests are to wear as is spent in describing the tabernacle (which is a type for God's garment, and thus a type for us), and there is great significance in these details, as they are the spiritual conditon of the priests.
- The three step process of becoming a priest (Ex. 40.13): Put on the priestly garment, be annointed, be consecrated:

> And you will clothe Aaron with the holy garments, and you will anoint
> him, and you will consecrate him, and he will serve as a priest for
> me.

- The danger of not having your flesh be fully covered by your garment, as in Ex. 20.26:

> You will not go up with steps onto my altar, that your nakedness not
> be exposed on it.

- The damnation of nakedness (Lamentations 1.8, Ezek. 23.18, Hos. 2.10)

> Jerusalem sinned grievously, thus she became an objection of derision;
> all those who honored her despise her because they have seen her
> nakedness. She herself groans and turns away.
>
> And she revealed her whorings, and she revealed her nakedness, and so
> I turned from her just as I turned from her sister.
>
> And now I will uncover her nakedness before the eyes of her lovers,
> and no one will rescue her from my hand.

- Prohibitions on *exposing someone else's nakedness* (Lev 18-20 and elsewhere, e.g. 18.8):

> You must not expose the nakedness of your father’s wife—it is your
> father’s nakedness.
>
> As for a man who lies with his aunt, he has exposed his uncle’s
> nakedness—they shall bear their sin; they shall die childless

- and therefore why "nakedness of the land" refers to the weaknesses of the land (Gen 42.12)

> Then he said to them, “No, but you have come to see the nakedness of
> the land.”

- The blessings of covering someone else's nakedness (2 Chron 28.15)

> Then the men designated by name arose and took the captives and from
> the plunder clothed all their nakedness. So they clothed them, gave
> them sandals, gave them food to eat, gave them water to drink,
> anointed them, and guided them with the donkeys provided for all those
> who stumbled, and brought them to Jericho, the city of the palm trees,
> next to their brothers. Then they returned to Samaria.

- and thus the obedience of Shem and Japheth in Gen 9.23:

> Then Shem and Japheth took a garment, and the two of them put it on
> their shoulders and, walking backward, they covered the nakedness of
> their father. And their faces were turned backward, so that they did
> not see the nakedness of their father.

- and Hanun's terrible insult to David's men:

> So Hanun took the servants of David and shaved them and cut off their
> garments at the middle, up to the buttocks, and sent them away.

- Why Jacob took Esau's blessing by wearing his garments (Gen 27.15) which convinced Isaac that Jacob was Esau:

> Then Rebekah took some of her older son Esau’s best garments that were
> with her in the house, and she put them on Jacob her younger son.

- Why Ruth, being covered by Boaz' garment, was redeemed by him:

> And he said, “Who are you?” And she said, “I am Ruth, your servant.
> Spread your garment over your servant because you are a redeemer.”

- The enormous attention paid to washing your garment (Lev 11) even when doing things (like eating or touching someone who had a wet dream) that would be unlikely to disproportionately dirty your garment (remember these were people living in the desert without access to soap):

> And the one who eats some of its dead body must wash his garments, and
> he shall be unclean until the evening; and the one who carries its
> dead body must wash his garments, and he shall be unclean until the
> evening.
>
> And the person who touches the body of the person who discharges must
> wash his garments, and he shall wash himself with water, and he shall
> be unclean until the evening.
>
> “And the person who sends out the goat for Azazel shall wash his
> garments, and he shall wash his body with water, and afterward he
> shall come to the camp. Lev 16.26
>
> Lev 11.25 and anyone who carries their dead body must wash his
> garments, and he shall be unclean until the evening.

- The need to ceremonially purify your garment (Numbers 8.21)

> And the Levites purified themselves, and they washed their garments,
> and Aaron offered them as a wave offering before Yahweh; and Aaron
> made atonement for them to purify them.

- God sees our sins in our garments:

> your iniquities and the iniquities of your ancestors together, says
> Yahweh, because they made smoke offerings on the mountains and they
> taunted me on the hills, I will measure their punishment from the
> beginning into the fold of their garment.”  Isa 61.10

- The need for a pure garment:

> I will rejoice greatly in Yahweh; my being shall shout in exultation
> in my God. For he has clothed me with garments of salvation, he has
> covered me with the robe of righteousness, as a bridegroom adorns
> himself with a head wrap like a priest, and as a bride adorns herself
> with her jewelry. Isa. 61.10

- Why repentance is signifyed by tearing your garments (as you now realize your existing spiritual state is filthy and are in need of new garments)  2 Chron 34.27

> because your heart was responsive and you humbled yourself before God
> when you heard his words against this place and against its
> inhabitants and you humbled yourself before me and tore your garments
> and wept before me, now I also have heard,’ declares Yahweh.

- The spiritual significance of men dividing Christ's garments among them:

> They divide my garments among them, and for my clothing they cast
> lots.

- The vision of Zechariah of the high priest:

> Zechariah 3:3–7 (LEB) And Joshua was clothed in filthy garments and
> was standing before the angel.
>
> And he answered and said to the ones standing before him, saying,
> “Remove the filthy garments from him.” And he said to him, “See, I
> have taken away your guilt from you, and will clothe you with rich
> garments.”
>
> And I said, “Let them put a clean headband on his head.” And they put
> a clean headband on his head, and they clothed him with garments. And
> the angel of Yahweh was standing by.
>
> And the angel of Yahweh assured Joshua, saying,
>
> “Thus says Yahweh of hosts: ‘If you will walk in my ways, and if you
> will keep my requirements, then you will judge my house, and you will
> also guard my courtyards, and I will give to you passageways among
> these that are standing here.

- The parable of the Wedding in Matthew (22.11-13)

> But when the king came in to see the dinner guests, he saw a man there
> not dressed in wedding clothes. And he said to him, ‘Friend, how did
> you come in here, not having wedding clothes?’ But he could say
> nothing. Then the king said to the servants, ‘Tie him up hand and foot
> and throw him into the outer darkness. In that place there will be
> weeping and gnashing of teeth!’

- and thus we are to hate the garment spotted by the flesh (Jude 23):

> and save others by snatching them from the fire, and have mercy on
> others with fear, hating even the tunic stained by the flesh.

- The importance of garments in revelation:

> But you have a few people in Sardis who have not defiled their
> clothing, and they will walk with me in white, because they are
> worthy. The one who conquers in this way will be dressed in white
> clothing, and I will never erase his name from the book of life, and I
> will declare his name before my Father and before his angels. rev
> 3.4-5

- Why James cared about garments with holes in them:

> Your wealth has rotted, and your clothing has become moth-eaten. James
> 5.2

- And Peter wants us to be clothed in humility:

> In the same way, younger men, be subject to the elders, and all of you
> clothe yourselves with humility toward one another, because God
> opposes the proud, but gives grace to the humble.

Comment: You seem to be saying that sin can be 'covered' if it is 'not within God's line of sight'. Have I understood correctly ? You seem to imply that a 'spiritual condition' can 'hide' sin from God's 'sight'. I also notice that you never once refer to 'the righteousness of God' (which is by faith) nor do you once refer to the blood of Christ. The term 'holographic' is not anywhere in scripture nor have you explained what 'holographic' means. I do not see anything in this answer that is remotely scriptural. It is just a list of passages about clothing.

Comment: The "you seem to be saying" is usually a tip off that some terrible confusion will follow instead of an accurate characterization. Please re-read the post and pay special attention to clues like "Now the correct interpretation of this is not to say X" before asking me if I mean X.

Answer (score 0):

This comment is aimed towards Nigel.  Your concerns are the same concerns of the church, who sadly, is in a current need of reform.  There was no Blood of Christ when the old Testament was written, and there is no mention of God's righteousness, because it does not apply here.

God is not a man with man-attributes.
•Man's righteousness-characteristic is Man's belief that God is who he says he is, and will do what he says he will do.
•God's righteousness-characteristic is his ability to save that which is lost.

God says that he saves us for his name's sake; not because we are worthy.  And we believe him out of love and fear.

The goal in these posts is to understand what it says specifically in the passage of  Exodus 28:42.  This is why the Blood of Christ wasn't mentioned- he wasn't born when Exodus was written.  So does the words in Exodus equate to Hyperbole?  No.  Robert gives an excellent answer.  Your comment is based off of what Robert was careful to point out -=NOT=- to do: "superimposing an English idiom onto the Hebrew, and we are trying to understand the Hebrew". The holography which Robert speaks is about the word-canon; the head-imagery common to people of the time.

The fact is, God has no limit of vocabulary, where as us humans need word pictures to get across the point of what is happening.  So when one reads about covering up the physical flesh so as not to incur guilt, asking "is this done for effector hyperbole" is a valid question, when no other common sense answer remains.

So answering this question gives you insight into just HOW Jesus' blood covers our sin- by paying the cost of the transgression.

But such belief in NO WAY changes our spiritual condition before God.  Matthew 5:17 Do not think that I have come to abolish the law of Moses...→ Therefore those who do the law will be great in heaven and those that do not will be least in heaven.

Those who are in heaven will simply believe that Jesus will pay for their sins, but this doesn't change the condition of the flesh.  We mush be Born again.

"Does this mean we are to re-enter into mothers and come out once more?"- Never mind that now :-)  Point being is we will be given new bodies uncorruptable!  Not after the flesh of Adam, but prefigured after Jesus.  The timing of this happens at the end, so the correction of our spiritual condition can only be covered for a time when dealing with God... Thus all this text.

I hope this information finds all who read it well.

Comment: The answer space is for answers to the original question posted not for commenting to other individuals. This is not a forum like Reddit. I have voted to delete this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/45919)